# ¿Porque no se envia la tecla?

Tags: python, keyboard

Estoy intentado hacer un macro, pero el programa no me detecta el envio de la tecla "Enter" estoy usando

```
keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
```

el mismo se envia si habro la caja de mensajes, pero para abrirla no me estaria funcionando, intente tambien con :

```
keyboard.send('Enter')
```

pero de ninguna forma es posible abrirla, podrian decirme cual es el posible error?

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui as pa

keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
pa.typewrite("texto generado anteriormente")
keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
```

la caja de mensajes que quiero abrir esta en un programa, en caso de que sea el programa que niegue la peticion existe alguna otra libreria que pueda usar?

Comment: La libraría `keyboard` solo corre con cuenta *root* en Linux. En Windows, no se. ¿Solucionaste eso?

Comment: No sé si importe, pero siempre que he visto usos de esta librería, usan `enter` en minúscula.

Comment: hola no sabria decirte lo del root, pero los comandos funcionan en un .txt hice testeos para ver si estaba mal algo, pero simplemente no me abre la caja de mensajes todo lo demas funciona en un .txt

Answer (score 0):

logre solucionarlo cambiando la parte a esto:

```
keyboard.press('Enter')
time.sleep(0.05)
keyboard.release('Enter')
```

simplemente agregando el tiempo de espera se soluciono.